# 'no driver for sqlite3 found' in fresh rails install on windows 7 machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Gem file looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.18'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.18'
end

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

I get that error message when I try to go to /pages/home.

I am following the railstutorial guide and am at this point: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code:pages_routes

Btw, I am using sqlite3 as my db for now - if you were wondering.

Any ideas?

Edit: When I load the page, I am seeing a windows error message that says "ruby.exe - Entry point not found: The procedure entry point rb_str2cstr could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt-ruby191.dll".

Then it shows the error message in the browser.

Comment: What happens when on the ruby command line you do "gem install sqlite3"

Comment: It successfully installed sqlite3, but when I refresh the page I am seeing the same thing.

Comment: Btw, when I run bundle install on that gemfile again, it shows me that sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5) is being used.

Comment: dang I have the same problem.  I changed the line in GemFile like you did, and rand bundle install, but I still get the error

Comment: There seems to be a lot of questions related to this problem.  I wonder if there is actually a bug with the sqlite driver?

Comment: Thanks to everybody changed
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3' to gem 'sqlite3', :require => 'sqlite3' in Gemfile after doing new sqlite gem install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by re-creating my app, and in the initial `bundle install`, I changed the gem file to just have:

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

and not:

```
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
```

This seems to work. For whatever reason, that version of sqlite3 was not agreeing with my setup.

Comment: This worked for me.  I wonder if there is some kind of bug with version 1.2.5?  I noticed that when I removed the version specification it changed to 1.3.1, which works!

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue on a windows vista system and got it working by downloading the precompiled binaries for windows from the sqlite website:

http://sqlite.org/download.html

once I downloaded the shell and the dll (I would have posted the links directly but this site will only allow me to post 1!!!) to my desktop I extracted them to the **C:\Ruby192\bin** folder and then ran:

**gem install sqlite3-ruby**

from the command line.

My issue is now fully resolved. Hope that helps.